A mistake in Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds about proving if $D$ has measure zero in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, then $\int_{Q}f$ exists
A mistake in Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds about proving if $D$ has measure zero in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, then $\int_{Q}f$ exists
In Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds, page 94 Theorem 11.2 it states: Divide the collection of all subrectangles $R$ determined by $P$ into two disjoint subcollections $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{R^\prime}$, so that each rectangle $R\in \mathcal{R}$ lies in one of the rectangles $Q_i$, and each rectangle $R\in \mathcal{R^\prime}$ lies in one of the rectangles $Q_j^{\prime}$.
Here are my questions.
(i) It is possible that $\mathcal{R}$ is an empty subcollection even though $D$ is not empty. Am I right?
(ii) Munkres only deals with the case that $\mathcal{R}$ is not empty. We also need to consider the case that $\mathcal{R}$ is empty. Am I right?
Consider the case $\mathcal{R}$ is empty.
We have:
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{R\in\mathcal{R}^{\prime}}(M_{R}(f)-m_{R}(f))v(R)\leq2\epsilon^{\prime}\sum_{R\in\mathcal{R}^{\prime}}v(R)\leq2\epsilon^{\prime}v(Q)
\end{equation*}
We have:
\begin{align}
U(f,P)-L(f,P)&=\left(\sum_{R\in\mathcal{R}^{\prime}}(M_{R}(f)-m_{R}(f))v(R)\right)\\
 &\leq2v(Q)\epsilon^{\prime}\\
 &=2v(Q)\cdot[\epsilon/(2M+2v(Q))]\\
 &<\epsilon
\end{align}
This a question from Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds. I show you the whole context of the question below.


